# Setting empty string in headerText attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have JSF data table and only one column has column header.

I need to hide the column with header text based on the condition and when I do that the entire header row shrinks because the other columns don't have header text.

To prevent this, I need to set 'empty' string and I tried a few tricks but nothing seem to work.

```
<p:dataTable ....>                    
                                    
    <p:column headerText=" " >
```

How do I set empty string headerText attribute?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Primefaces version you could use this code to force the creation of the html element

```
<p:dataTable ....>                    
                                    
    <p:column headerText="&nbsp;" >
```

With early version this should create the div but make it very small, so you can add css style to adjust to your wish, something like

```
.ui-datatable thead th {
   min-height: xx px;
   min-width: yy px;
}
```

I think you can solve your problem event with only the second part, so only with css.

Comment: ok, your comment helped me to solve this issue. thanks!